# "UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking" con html2text

Tags: bash

Estoy programando en bash y exportando información a un archivo pero no se me guarda de manera correcta. ¿Alguien sabe por qué? Estoy utilizando el siguiente comando:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s "https://www.blockchain.com/es/btc/unconfirmed-transactions" | html2text > 
ut.tmp
```

El error que produce es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si puede estar relacionado con un problema de codificación.

Comment: UTF-8 Unicode text, with overstriking

Comment: o sea, que la corrupcion la hace el html2text, no?

Comment: leo por ahi que uno lo arregló actualizando  poppler y html2text

Comment: Concretamente hablan de un caso como el tuyo usando html2text (tambien con mac) en este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961862/html2text-strange-buffered-output-issue-when-writing-output-file

Comment: Yo con Word no he creado nada jeje

Comment: Si, una vez me llegó una advertencia XSS de NoScritp, pero no se si tiene algo que ver.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando `html2text -utf8 > ut.tmp`.
También hay otras opciones de formato, puedes verlas con `html2text -help`.

Comment: Me da este error: Unrecognized command line option "-utf8", try "-help".

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que `html2text` enriquece el texto añadiendolé otros caracteres para que pueda ser leido por paginadores como `more` o `less`. Es decir, si utilizas ese comando y lo pipeas a `less`, todo lo verás super bien:

```
$ curl -s "https://www.blockchain.com/es/btc/unconfirmed-transactions" | html2text | less
```

La cosa aquí es que puedes evitar ese enriquecimiento añadiéndole el parámetro `-nobs`:

```
$ curl -s "https://www.blockchain.com/es/btc/unconfirmed-transactions" | html2text -nobs > tmp.txt
```

Y ya luego podrás leer bien tu archivo de texto.